# undefined is not a function(evaluating '_navigationactions2.default.reset')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native, I just follow react navigation official docs and try to use drawerNavigator and stackNavigator.
When I access drawerNavigator from the second screen of stackNavigator shows error: undefined is not a function(evaluating '_navigationactions2.default.reset'). 
Simply said, how can I access drawer from anywhere.

Here is App.js:

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Button,
    Image
} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to Details"
                    onPress={() => {
                        /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                            itemId: 86,
                            otherParam: 'anything you want here',
                        });
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}


class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        /* 2. Read the params from the navigation state */
        const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
        const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;
        const otherParam = params ? params.otherParam : null;

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Text>Details Screen</Text>
                <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
                <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Go to Details... again"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
                />
                <Button
                    title="Go back"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}


class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'DrawerHome',
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Image
                source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
        ),
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
                title="Go to notifications"
            />
        );
    }
}

class MyNotificationsScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        drawerLabel: 'Notifications',
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Image
                source={require('./notif-icon.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
        ),
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Button
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
                title="Go back home"
            />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    icon: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
    },
});

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
        },
        Details: {
            screen: DetailsScreen,
        },
    }
);

const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
        Home: {
            screen: MyHomeScreen,
        },
        Notifications: {
            screen: MyNotificationsScreen,
        },
        Stack: {
            screen: RootStack,
        }
    }
);


export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <MyApp/>;
    }
}
```

react version: 16.3.1

react-native version: 0.55.3

Please help me.

error from AVD, android version: 6.0
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDTyY.png

Comment: Please post more code, where did you get error?

Comment: Your imports are wrong, unless you're initializing them anywhere else `import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';` `const RootStack = StackNavigator(` and similarly for `DrawerNavigator`

Comment: @anhtu complete code already added. Thanks for your helping in advance.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I used to import { StackNavigator }, but it gave me warning that StackNavigator is deprecated. Then I found NavigationPlayground example uses createStackNavigator. Here is the link: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/Drawer.js

Comment: Sorry, the master branch is on the version `2.0.0`, therefore it is different.

Comment: @KurtZ thank for the code. But when/where did you get the error? From `Detail`?